# ObjC - how to read a BIN file from server with NSJSONSerialization

Tags: objective-c, binary, nsjsonserialization

I have managed to read  a .BIN file from a local path of my project and then complete my coding steps as i desire but now i want, this BIN file to obtain it with NSJSONSerialization  from the server and then add it to a path i use to validate it and finally from there continue as before...

at first i only had the following class

```
- (IBAction)selectImagePressed:(id)sender {
    NSMutableString *path= [[NSMutableString  alloc] initWithString: [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    [path appendString:@"/"] ;
    [path appendString:@"myBINFile.bin"];
    [self validateImage:path];
}
```

But now i want to obtain the bin from a server, this is what i have written so far:

```
- (void)simpleJsonParsingMethod
{
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@api/v1/Firmware/%ld", BASE_URL, (long)self.d.my.identifier];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/octet-stream" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
  {
      if(!error)
      {
          NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];//tmpFilePath
          [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
      }

  }] resume];
}
```

I am stuck now here and not sure how can i proceed to add the filename to the initial call (:path)

```
- (IBAction)selectImagePressed:(id)sender
```